# Can Apex log into 3rd parties that accept Salesforce OAuth on behalf of a running user?

Tags: apex, api, oauth2, pardot

I know I can write a Heroku project that lets a Salesforce user log into my Heroku app with Salesforce over OAuth -- it's been a while, but I've done it.

And therefore, in theory, that should be all I need to write a custom application that lets a Salesforce user from my org do things in Pardot that normally I'd have to do over the API, now that Salesforce is turning on OAuth for Pardot's API.

What would be fun, though, is to be able to make functionality *within* Salesforce's UI *(buttons, screen flows, lightning components, etc.)* that says, "Who's the logged-in user clicking this button?" and tries to perform actions against Pardot's API using those credentials.

Is it possible to stand up user interfaces *within* Salesforce that do something along the lines of `UserInfo.getSessionId()` but ... with OAuth instead?

Comment: Have you explored Named Credentials?